# Why are all files marked with 'merge' in TFS?

Tags: tfs, merge, tfs-power-tools

I am merging my development branch into the main branch.  There is only a subset of files that I have changed in my development branch, all other files should remain unchanged.  Logically, I only want to merge files which I've changed.  I would not check in a file which I did not change.

But when I do the merge operation in TFS, it marks every single file in the tree with change type 'merge'.  It looks like I must checkin every single file in the whole source code tree!  I really do not want to do this becasue then it becomes impossible to look at the changeset and see what files I acctually changed as part of my project.

At first, I thought I could use the tfpt.exe Undo Unchanged command to undo all the 'merge' changes, but this won't undo those changes.

Anyone have any ideas on this?  thanks.

Comment: We have TFS 2008 but visual studio 2005

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of possible reasons.  This is not a complete list:

- You performed a namespace operation (delete, undelete, rename) on a parent folder of the 
  files marked "merge"
- You performed a namespace operation (delete, undelete, rename) that had already been performed in the target branch
- You performed a sequence of namespace operations that collapsed into a no-op (eg delete + undelete, or rename a -> b -> a)
- There are unresolved conflicts
- You performing a discard

Note: all of these apply equally to 2005 & 2008.

Comment: It also happens if you rename your branch, it would appear.

Comment: ^ Yup.  Might consider it a special case of #1, but "root renames" actually do have special handling in TFS, so worth calling out...thanks.

Comment: This happens frequently in our TFS 2010 server.  And we have done none of the things in your list.

Answer (score 10):

This also happens with a baseless merge. A baseless merge occurs when TFS doesn't have an existing merge relationship between the branches you're merging. As a result, it considers every file 'new' in both branches, so it 'merges' every file.

To create a merge relationship, so that future merges only list the files that you've actually changed, you need to do a baseless merge of all changes up to a specified version so that TFS knows what the common baseline should be. You should do this **after** merging these changes - it's too late to correct the baseline for this branch now.

If you don't actually want to take any changes from the other branch, but just tell TFS that these are logically at the same version, you can do a merge 'giving credit' for the changesets: `tf merge /discard`.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2008 and TFS 2008, this does not occur.  Only files that have changed will be marked as merge.  If you do a compare of a file between the branch and the trunk are there any changes?  Changes such as encoding will still make TFS merge this file back.

Comment: Great!  I have TFS 2008 but VS 2005, so I guess this is a function of the client.

Comment: No, pending changes are computed entirely on the server.  See the VersionControlServer.QueryPendingSets() API for details.

Comment: Exactly. Either way, encoding changes or any code changes will mark this as requiring a merge.

Comment: Still happens with TFS 2010 and VS 2010

Comment: Indeed, this still happens, even with VSTS online.